# how to store NSDictionary as transformable properties in core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-data

I have a `NSDictionary` in which I wanted to store in my core data model. How can I do this?

Answer (score 10):

Set the attribute to Transformable and this serializes it to and from NSData automatically for you. No need to manually archive as in the other answer.

Answer (score 8):

Use NSKeyedArchiver and store it in data field in your DB :

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:yourDictionary];
```